# Dragon ball Xenoverse: I finished all paralell quest offline but with 2 of the chapters i get no clear. Is there something i missed?

Tags: dragon-ball-xenoverse

I've been level 80 for a while now, and I have finished the entire story. I have finished all the parallel quests as well, but with the quest with 6 stars and 8 stars I didn't get my clear.  Did I miss something?

Comment: Have you Talked to all people to get all parralell quests ? Sometimes the are not available at the lil robot and you need to Talk to other people to get them. A hint is to look if the Quest row is complete and there is no jumps in them like Quest 1 - 2 - 4 ... etc if there is one missing you know wich quest to look for

Comment: Yeah i did, i have finished all the quests they give me, the one from gohan kid, gohan teen, Majin bu, thrunks kid.. all those are already finished

Comment: so you have all 55 quest ? without any exceptions ? and all the Bonus Quest goals ?

Comment: I dont have all the bonus goals, but you don't need them to finish the quest and clear it... But i will try to get all the bonus goals to get the ultimate finish, maybe that helps :)